# Max out 32 GB of Ram with only 2 slots

Tags: memory, desktop-computer

I'm very interested in this [computer](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883101264&ignorebbr=1), but looking under specifications it says it only has two slots, yet can maximize up to 32 gb of RAM. Is this possible, or is it a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that the i7 6700 can handle [up to 64GB](https://ark.intel.com/products/88196/Intel-Core-i7-6700-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_00-GHz), most likely across 4 slots, it is quite likely that this is **not** a typo and the processor is happy with 16GB DIMMS.

From experience I can tell you that it *does* work with 16GB DIMMS, so 32GB in 2 slots is not surprising.